# using foundation 6 scss with angular 2 cli

Tags: angular, zurb-foundation-6, angular-cli

How to use foundation 6 with angular cli.I tried with plain scss but was unable to proceed with foundation 6 scss.How should I proceed with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you use the angular cli or the webpack starter package?

With webpack it's very straightforward to implement foundation. At the moment i'm using [Angular2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack).

1. Install foundation-sites via npm
2. Import foundation-sites in your vendor.ts file. Like so:

   import 'foundation-sites';
3. Import foundation scss file in your app.scss like this:

   @import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation'
4. Include your preferred mixins.

   @include foundation-global-styles;
   @include foundation-typography;

**Angular CLI (without webpack)**

To include external sass files in your project, you have to change the angular cli build file. The angular cli is based on the ember cli and uses broccoli to compile your assets. There is a excellent article about this on the [codementor website](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/compiling-sass-postcss-with-angular-cli).

In short you have to install extra node_modules for broccoli and change your angular-cli-build.js file.

Run the following command to install the extra node_modules:

```
npm i broccoli-sass broccoli-merge-trees lodash glob broccoli-postcss postcss-cssnext cssnano --save
```

For reference here is my angular-cli-build.js

```
const Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');
const compileSass = require('broccoli-sass');
const compileCSS = require('broccoli-postcss');
const cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
const _ = require('lodash');
const glob = require('glob');

var options = {
    plugins: [
        {
            module: cssnext,
            options: {
                browsers: ['> 1%'],
                warnForDuplicates: false
            }
        },
        {
            module: cssnano,
            options: {
                safe: true,
                sourcemap: true
            }
        }
    ]
};


module.exports = function (defaults) {
    let appTree = new Angular2App(defaults, {
        sassCompiler: {
            cacheExclude: [/\/_[^\/]+$/],
            includePaths: [
                'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/util',
                'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation',
                'src/assets/styles'
            ]
        },
        vendorNpmFiles: [
            'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
            'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
            'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
            'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
            '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
        ]
    });

    let sass = mergeTrees(_.map(glob.sync('src/**/*.scss'), function (sassFile) {
        sassFile = sassFile.replace('src/', '');
        return compileSass(['src'], sassFile, sassFile.replace(/.scss$/, '.css'));
    }));

    let css = compileCSS(sass, options);

    return mergeTrees([appTree, sass, css], { overwrite: true });
};
```

In your .scss file you can include foundation sass file like this:

```
@import "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation";
```

Comment: is it better to use foundation-apps instead of foundation-sites when using with angular 2 apps

Comment: Foundation Apps 1 is based on Angular 1.x. The work for Foundation for Apps 2 will started soon when Angular 2.x is reaching a stable version.

There is a thread on the Foundation forms about this: [link](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/39392-angular-2-and-foundation-6)

So at the moment i recommend using foundation sites, and activate the flexbox mode. With flexbox you can easily create a app like feeling. More about the flexbox mode here: [link](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flexbox.html)

Comment: @FrankSpin How can I import specific Foundation Js modules in vendor.ts ?

Answer (score 16):

Create a new "sassy" Project with the Angular CLI:

```
ng new sassy-project --style=sass
```

Then install Foundation Sites via NPM:

```
npm install foundation-sites --save
```

Finally import the Foundation SASS-File in the projects **styles.scss** file:

```
@import "../node_modules/foundation-sites/assets/foundation";
```

For more Details:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#css-preprocessor-integration

Comment: `ng new` documentation. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/new.md

Comment: Thanks!   I was including ~/scss/foundation.scss, including ~/assets/foundation.scss instead solved my issue!

Comment: Thank you! You also could be interested by using the settings file. To do so, copy node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/settings/_settings.scss into assets/styles/foundation-settings.scss, fix the path of util/util import in your copied file to @import '~foundation-sites/scss/util/util'; instead and import your settings *before* your main foundation file in styles.scss ...